# How to setup disposable email aliases (craigslist style)?

Tags: c#, email, email-spam

Writing my own "craigslist" in .NET, trying to figure out how to create disposable email aliases (craigslist type)?

> Here's what I mean by "craigslist
>   style".
>
> My website is: somecoolurl.com
>
> User creates an account, but doesn't
>   want to give his/her email out as contact when posting on the site.
>
> I want to give the user a TEMP email
>   asdflkasfdjlaksdj@somecoolurl.com and
>   alias that to their real email. When
>   the user wants to get a new email, the
>   TEMP gets canned and a new email gets
>   created.

Comment: Can you describe what "craigslist style" is for people who aren't familiar with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about email address piping? Check out this SO question [Best way to send anonymous email like craigslist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745124/best-way-to-send-anonymous-email-like-craigslist)

Here is how to [pipe incomming mail on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926345/pipe-incoming-email-to-a-script-on-windows-iis-smtp)

Comment: Implementation example would be interesting for me too. Especialy using IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, not exactly sure what you're referring to with "craigslist" but I do know that in an app that I currently built, I purchased the SmarterMail app from http://smartertools.com and used their .NET API as part of my software.

When a user signs up and pays, I generate a random string (you could make it more meaningful if you want) and then append it to the domain name (fke34s@example.com)

From there I create the email address via the SmarterMail API and assign the password based on the users existing password.

Then I have a watcher the checks to see if the paid subscription lapses... if it does, I disable the account for X days.  If the user doesn't renew after X days, the watcher deletes the account (this keeps my total users down since I didn't pay for the unlimited license yet).

Works very well.

Comment: will emails sent to fke34s@example.com be forwarded to user's real email? can you create x123@example.com and re-alias it with user's real email?

Comment: Yes you can create alias's as well.  My users wanted a private email that did not get mixed in with their regular accounts, so I never bothered.  But it is possible to make aliases.

Comment: look here "do a find for the word Alias" - http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterMail/Compare-Mail-Server-Editions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Set up a catch-all account. Then use C# to log in with IMAP or POP and forward according to your rules.